# Como preencher combobox com consulta SQL? C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, oledb

Gostaria de saber se é possível passar os dados de uma consulta SQL para um combobox utilizando C#. Pesquisei sobra o assunto e encontrei exemplos, porem quando adaptei para o meu caso , não consegui utilizar. Estou fazendo desta maneira:

```
private void carregacombo()
{
    Conexao conexão = new Conexao();
    try
    {
        conexão.conectar();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select nomeEquipe from Equipe",conexão.cn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dtMensagens = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtMensagens);
        this.cmbEquipe.DataSource = dtMensagens;
        this.cmbEquipe.DisplayMember = "nomeEquipe";

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conexão.desconectar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @Felipe. Qual o problema? A `ComboBox` não fica preenchida? Tem de detalhar mais o seu problema.

Answer (score -2):

Descobri o meu erro, a query deveria estar no OleDbDataAdapter e a linha de OleDbCommand não existe. No fim o código ficou desta maneira:

```
private void carregacombo()
    {
        Conexao conexão = new Conexao();
        try
        {
            conexão.conectar();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select idEquipe,nomeEquipe from Equipe", conexão.cn);
            DataTable dtMensagens = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtMensagens);
            this.cmbEquipe.DataSource = dtMensagens;
            this.cmbEquipe.ValueMember = "idEquipe";
            this.cmbEquipe.DisplayMember = "nomeEquipe";

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conexão.desconectar();
        }
    }
```